# Generate dynamic multilevel XML file from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, merge

I have a database with 5 tables. 3 tables are connect .

I create one table where all data is merged. This table has a column GroupLevel that holds then level nr. Each level holds the subsequent lower level, e.g. group 1 holds group 2.

The first of my tables contains products:

```
 ProductID  ProductLanguageID   ProductDefaultShopID  ProductNumber ProductName ProductPrice
    100101@@SHOP1   LANG2           SHOP1                 100101            AAA         159,61
    100102@@SHOP1   LANG2           SHOP1                 100102            BBB         159,61
    100105@@SHOP1   LANG2           SHOP1                 100105            CCC         159,61
```

the second has groups:

```
GroupID         GroupLanguageID      GroupName  GroupNumber
1@@SHOP1    LANG2                ABC        1
1.01@@SHOP1 LANG2                BCD    1.01
1.02@@SHOP1 LANG2                CDE    1.02
1.03@@SHOP1 LANG2                DEF    1.03
```

the third languages

```
LanguageID  LanguageCode2   LanguageName    LanguageNativeName
LANG1           En          English         English
LANG2           De          German          Deutsch
```

I have also 2 tables that don´t have any connections to another tables:

Group Relations Table

```
GroupRelationsGroupID   GroupRelationsParentID
1.01@@SHOP1         1@@SHOP1
1.02@@SHOP1         1@@SHOP1
1.02@@SHOP1         1@@SHOP1
```

Group Product Relation Table

```
GroupProductRelationGroupID GroupProductRelationProductID
1.01@@SHOP1                 576134@@SHOP1
1.01@@SHOP1                 327112@@SHOP1
1.01@@SHOP1                 457168@@SHOP1
1.01@@SHOP1                 457220@@SHOP1
1.03@@SHOP1                 457221@@SHOP1
1.03@@SHOP1                 163704@@SHOP1
1.03@@SHOP1                 163705@@SHOP1
1.03@@SHOP1                 163706@@SHOP1
```

I created one table where all data is merged. This table has a column GroupLevel that holds a level nr. Each level holds the subsequent lower level, e.g. group 1 holds group 2, as in table below

```
GroupLevel  GroupID GroupLanguageID GroupName  GroupNumber  ParentGroupID  GroupProductRelationGroupID GroupProductRelationProductID  ProductID ProductLanguageID  ProductNumber  ProductName   ProductPrice
1       1@@SHOP1    LANG2           ABC    1            NULL           NULL                    NULL                           NULL          NULL               NULL           NULL          NULL
2       1.01@@SHOP1 LANG2           BCD    1.01         1@@SHOP1       1.01@@SHOP1             457163@@SHOP1              457163@@SHOP1 LANG2              457163     ProductName   299,81
2       1.01@@SHOP1 LANG2           BCD    1.01         1@@SHOP1       1.01@@SHOP1             457162@@SHOP1              457162@@SHOP1 LANG2              457162     ProductName   163,14
2       1.03@@SHOP1 LANG2           DEF    1.03         1@@SHOP1       1.03@@SHOP1             159151@@SHOP1              159151@@SHOP1 LANG2              159151     ProductName   10
2       1.03@@SHOP1 LANG2           DEF    1.03         1@@SHOP1       1.03@@SHOP1             159150@@SHOP1              159150@@SHOP1 LANG2              159150     ProductName   10
2       1.03@@SHOP1 LANG2           DEF    1.02         1@@SHOP1       1.03@@SHOP1             159122@@SHOP1              159122@@SHOP1 LANG2              159122     ProductName   309,35
3       1.13@@SHOP1 LANG2           GGG    1.13         1.03@@SHOP1    1.13@@SHOP1             3459652@@SHOP1             3459652@@SHOP1LANG2              3459652    ProductName   309,35  
4       1.14@@SHOP1 LANG2           BBB    1.14         1.13@@SHOP1    1.13@@SHOP1             564326@@SHOP1              564326@@SHOP1 LANG2              564326     ProductName   309,35
```

My question is how to create a dynamical XML file with max 3 levels, where all items on levels after the third one are merged to(included into) the 3rd level. I also need that each item of these levels (the ones merged to the third) has an attribute that says/shows which level they originally belonged to. So for example if I had 5 levels and level 4 and 5 where merged into level 3, all items from level 4 should have a tag saying “previously in level 4” and from level 5 "previously in level 5". This should work regardless of how many levels there are.

I created code but it doesn't work as needed

```
SELECT lvl1.GroupName AS groupName, lvl1.GroupNumber
      ,(
            SELECT prod1.ProductName AS itemName
            ,prod1.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
            prod1.ProductPrice AS itemPrice,
            prod1.GroupID,
            prod1.GroupName                      
            FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod1
            WHERE prod1.GroupLevel=1 
            AND prod1.GroupID=lvl1.GroupID             
            FOR XML PATH('product'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                )
                ,(  

        SELECT  lvl2.GroupName AS groupName, lvl2.GroupNumber
           ,(

    SELECT  prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
           ,prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
    FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
    WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
        AND prod.GroupLevel=2
        AND prod.ProductID=lvl2.ProductID
        AND prod.GroupID=lvl2.GroupID
        FOR XML PATH('product'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
         )                      
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl2
        WHERE lvl2.GroupLevel=2 
        AND lvl2.ParentGroupID=lvl1.GroupID
        group by lvl2.GroupName , lvl2.GroupNumber,lvl2.GroupID, lvl2.ProductID
       FOR XML PATH('productGroup2'),TYPE
       )         
FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl1
WHERE lvl1.ParentGroupID IS NULL
group by lvl1.GroupName , lvl1.GroupNumber,lvl1.GroupID, lvl1.ProductID
FOR XML PATH('productgroup1'),ROOT('root')

GO
```

An example of how I need to do:

```
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' +
(

SELECT lvl1.GroupName AS groupName
      ,(
                SELECT prod1.ProductName, prod1.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                ,prod1.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS prod1
                WHERE prod1.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                AND prod1.GroupLevel=1
                AND prod1.ProductID=lvl1.ProductID
                AND prod1.GroupID=lvl1.GroupID


                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_1'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                )
                ,(  
SELECT  lvl2.GroupName AS 'GroupName'
                ,(
                SELECT prod2.ProductName  AS ProductName ,prod2.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                ,prod2.ProductPrice AS itemPrice, prod2.GroupID
                FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS prod2
                WHERE prod2.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                AND prod2.GroupLevel=2
                AND prod2.ProductID=lvl2.ProductID
                AND prod2.GroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                order by groupName
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_2'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                )
                ,(
SELECT lvl3.GroupName AS groupName
                ,(
                SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                ,prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice    
                FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS prod
                WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                AND prod.GroupLevel=3
                AND prod.ProductID= lvl3.ProductID
                AND prod.GroupID=lvl3.GroupID
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_3'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                )               
                ,(

                SELECT  prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                ,prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS prod
                WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                AND prod.GroupLevel=3
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_4'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                )

,(

                SELECT  prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
                ,prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS prod
                WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                AND prod.GroupLevel=5
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_5'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                )

FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS lvl3
WHERE lvl3.GroupLevel=3 
AND lvl3.ParentGroupID=lvl2.GroupID
FOR XML PATH('productGroup3'),TYPE, ELEMENTS
                )    
FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS lvl2
WHERE lvl2.GroupLevel=2 
AND lvl2.ParentGroupID=lvl1.GroupID
order by lvl2.GroupName
FOR XML PATH('productGroup2'),TYPE, ELEMENTS 
                )      
FROM tmpFullResultInDesign AS lvl1
WHERE lvl1.ParentGroupID IS NULL
order by GroupNumber
FOR XML PATH('productGroup1'),ROOT('root')
)
```

Output in XML Like this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
       <productGroup1>
              <groupName>Kosmetik</groupName>
              <productGroup2>
                     <GroupName>Face</GroupName>
                     <products>
                            <productLevel_2 id="Product1">
                                   <ProductName>AAAAA!</ProductName>
                                   <itemNumber>457162</itemNumber>
                                   <itemPrice>1.02</itemPrice>
                                   <GroupID>1.01@@SHOP1</GroupID>
                               </productLevel_2>
                            <productLevel_2 id="Product2">
                                   <ProductName>BBBBB!</ProductName>
                                   <itemNumber>43434234</itemNumber>
                                   <itemPrice>134.3434</itemPrice>
                                   <GroupID>1.01@@SHOP1</GroupID>
                               </productLevel_2>
                        </products>
                     <productGroup3>
                            <groupName>FFFFFFF</groupName>
                            <products>
                                   <productLevel_3 id="Product1">
                                          <itemNumber>123@1</itemNumber>
                                          <itemPrice>1.230000000000000e+002</itemPrice>
                                      </productLevel_3>
                               </products>
                            <products>
                                   <productLevel_previously_level_4 id="Product1">
                                          <itemNumber>23234545</itemNumber>
                                          <itemPrice>34.676</itemPrice>
                                      </productLevel_previously_level_4>
                                   <productLevel_previously_level_4 id="Product2">
                                          <itemNumber>23234545</itemNumber>
                                          <itemPrice>34.676</itemPrice>
                                      </productLevel_previously_level_4>
                               </products>
                        </productGroup3>
                 </productGroup2>
          </productGroup1>
   </root>
```

**Question Explain:** 
I need to work with n levels (i.e. level n+1 should go to level n). I try to explain once again... 
I have products on several levels:

```
level 1 + products 
level 2 + products 
level 3 + products ... 
level n + products.
```

The idea is if I choose level 1, all products from level bigger than 1 (i.e. 2, 3, 4...n) are aggregated to level 1:

```
<productGroup1 GroupID="10@@SHOP1">
       <GroupName>AAA</GroupName>
       <GroupLevel>1</GroupLevel>
       <products>
              <product>
                     <ProductName>CCC</ProductName>
                 </product>
          </products>
       <products>
              <product>
                     <ProductName>Mem</ProductName>
                 </product>
          </products>
   </productGroup1>
```

If I choose level 2, level 1 is intact and all products from level bigger than 2 (i.e. 3, 4...n) are aggregated to level 2. 
The same shall go for all levels (there is no limit).

Can I put CTE into the stored procedure?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the "merged" XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your "An example of how I need to do" and replaced level 4 and level 5 queries with this:

```
-- Levels 3+
SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id', prod.GroupLevel AS '@PreviousGroupLevel', prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
    prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
    AND prod.GroupLevel>= 3
--FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_4'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
FOR XML PATH('productLevel_HigherLevels'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
```

In the above, notice, that I am using an attribute "@PreviousGroupLevel" and that XML PATH changed to "productLevel_HigherLevels".
The overall query is below (it requires #tmpFullResult table):

```
SELECT lvl1.GroupName AS groupName,
    (
        SELECT prod1.ProductName, prod1.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
            ,prod1.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod1
        WHERE prod1.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
            AND prod1.GroupLevel = 1
            AND prod1.ProductID = lvl1.ProductID
            AND prod1.GroupID = lvl1.GroupID
        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_1'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
    ),
    (  
        SELECT  lvl2.GroupName AS 'GroupName',
            (
                SELECT prod2.ProductName  AS ProductName ,prod2.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                    prod2.ProductPrice AS itemPrice, prod2.GroupID
                FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod2
                WHERE prod2.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                    AND prod2.GroupLevel=2
                    AND prod2.ProductID=lvl2.ProductID
                    AND prod2.GroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                ORDER BY groupName
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_2'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
            ),
            (
                SELECT lvl3.GroupName AS groupName
                    ,(
                        SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice    
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                            AND prod.GroupLevel = 3
                            AND prod.ProductID = lvl3.ProductID
                            AND prod.GroupID = lvl3.GroupID
                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_3'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                    )               
                    ,(
                        -- Levels 3+
                        SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id', prod.GroupLevel AS '@PreviousGroupLevel', prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                            AND prod.GroupLevel>= 3
                        --FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_4'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_HigherLevels'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                    )/*,
                    (
                        SELECT  prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                            AND prod.GroupLevel=5
                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_5'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                    )*/
                FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl3
                WHERE lvl3.GroupLevel=3 
                AND lvl3.ParentGroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                FOR XML PATH('productGroup3'),TYPE, ELEMENTS
            )    
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl2
        WHERE lvl2.GroupLevel=2 
        AND lvl2.ParentGroupID=lvl1.GroupID
        order by lvl2.GroupName
        FOR XML PATH('productGroup2'),TYPE, ELEMENTS 
    )      
FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl1
WHERE lvl1.ParentGroupID IS NULL
order by GroupNumber
FOR XML PATH('productGroup1'),ROOT('root')
```

I hope this is what you have been looking for.

**Update:**
Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpFullResult( GroupLevel INT, GroupID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    GroupLanguageID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL, GroupName VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    GroupNumber DECIMAL( 10, 3 ) NULL, ParentGroupID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    GroupProductRelationGroupID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    GroupProductRelationProductID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL,
    ProductID VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL, ProductLanguageID VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL,
    ProductNumber INT NULL, ProductName VARCHAR( 20 ) NULL, ProductPrice DECIMAL( 20, 4 ) NULL )

INSERT INTO #tmpFullResult
VALUES
( 1, '1@@SHOP1',    'LANG2', 'ABC',    1,  NULL,           NULL,         NULL,            NULL,            NULL,   NULL,        NULL,          NULL ),
( 2, '1.01@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BCD', 1.01, '1@@SHOP1',    '1.01@@SHOP1', '457163@@SHOP1', '457163@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 457163,     'ProductName', 299.81 ),
( 2, '1.01@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BCD', 1.01, '1@@SHOP1',    '1.01@@SHOP1', '457162@@SHOP1', '457162@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 457162,     'ProductName', 163.14 ),
( 2, '1.03@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'DEF', 1.03, '1@@SHOP1',    '1.03@@SHOP1', '159151@@SHOP1', '159151@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 159151,     'ProductName', 10 ),
( 2, '1.03@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'DEF', 1.03, '1@@SHOP1',    '1.03@@SHOP1', '159150@@SHOP1', '159150@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 159150,     'ProductName', 10 ),
( 2, '1.03@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'DEF', 1.02, '1@@SHOP1',    '1.03@@SHOP1', '159122@@SHOP1', '159122@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 159122,     'ProductName', 309.35 ),
( 3, '1.13@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'GGG', 1.13, '1.03@@SHOP1', '1.03@@SHOP1', '3459652@@SHOP1','3459652@@SHOP1','LANG2', 3459652,    'ProductName', 309.35 ), 
( 4, '1.14@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BBB', 1.14, '1.13@@SHOP1', '1.13@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 564326,     'ProductName', 309.35 ),
( 5, '1.15@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BBB', 1.14, '1.14@@SHOP1', '1.13@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 564326,     'ProductName', 309.35 ),
( 3, '1.23@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'GGG', 1.13, '1.01@@SHOP1', '1.03@@SHOP1', '3459652@@SHOP1','3459652@@SHOP1','LANG2', 3459652,    'ProductName', 309.35 ), 
( 4, '1.24@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BBB', 1.14, '1.23@@SHOP1', '1.13@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 564326,     'ProductName', 309.35 ),
( 5, '1.25@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 'BBB', 1.14, '1.24@@SHOP1', '1.13@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', '564326@@SHOP1', 'LANG2', 564326,     'ProductName', 309.35 )
```

Below query is similar to the one above, except that I have added a CTE to calculate GroupLevel 3 parentID for all higher level groups:

```
;WITH productLevel_HigherLevels( GroupLevel, GroupID, GroupLanguageID, GroupName, GroupNumber, ParentGroupID,
        GroupProductRelationGroupID, GroupProductRelationProductID, ProductID, ProductLanguageID,
        ProductNumber, ProductName, ProductPrice )
AS  
-- Define the CTE query.  
(  
    SELECT GroupLevel, GroupID, GroupLanguageID, GroupName, GroupNumber, ParentGroupID,
        GroupProductRelationGroupID, GroupProductRelationProductID, ProductID, ProductLanguageID,
        ProductNumber, ProductName, ProductPrice
    FROM #tmpFullResult
    WHERE GroupLevel = 4 AND ProductID IS NOT NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT HigherLevel.GroupLevel, HigherLevel.GroupID, HigherLevel.GroupLanguageID, HigherLevel.GroupName, HigherLevel.GroupNumber, LowerLevel.ParentGroupID,
        HigherLevel.GroupProductRelationGroupID, HigherLevel.GroupProductRelationProductID, HigherLevel.ProductID, HigherLevel.ProductLanguageID,
        HigherLevel.ProductNumber, HigherLevel.ProductName, HigherLevel.ProductPrice
    FROM productLevel_HigherLevels AS LowerLevel
        INNER JOIN #tmpFullResult AS HigherLevel
                ON HigherLevel.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                    AND LowerLevel.GroupLevel + 1 = HigherLevel.GroupLevel
                    AND HigherLevel.ParentGroupID = LowerLevel.GroupID
)
SELECT lvl1.GroupName AS groupName,
    (
        SELECT prod1.ProductName, prod1.ProductNumber AS itemNumber
            ,prod1.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod1
        WHERE prod1.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
            AND prod1.GroupLevel = 1
            AND prod1.ProductID = lvl1.ProductID
            AND prod1.GroupID = lvl1.GroupID
        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_1'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
    ),
    (  
        SELECT  lvl2.GroupName AS 'GroupName',
            (
                SELECT prod2.ProductName  AS ProductName ,prod2.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                    prod2.ProductPrice AS itemPrice, prod2.GroupID
                FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod2
                WHERE prod2.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                    AND prod2.GroupLevel=2
                    AND prod2.ProductID=lvl2.ProductID
                    AND prod2.GroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                ORDER BY groupName
                FOR XML PATH('productLevel_2'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
            ),
            (
                SELECT lvl3.GroupName AS groupName
                    ,(
                        SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice    
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                            AND prod.GroupLevel = 3
                            AND prod.ProductID = lvl3.ProductID
                            AND prod.GroupID = lvl3.GroupID

                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_3'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                    )               
                    ,(
                        SELECT prod.ProductName  AS '@id', prod.GroupLevel AS '@PreviousGroupLevel', prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                        FROM productLevel_HigherLevels AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ParentGroupID = lvl3.GroupID
                        --FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_4'),ROOT('products'),TYPE
                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_HigherLevels'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                    )/*,
                    (
                        SELECT  prod.ProductName  AS '@id' ,prod.ProductNumber AS itemNumber,
                            prod.ProductPrice AS itemPrice
                        FROM #tmpFullResult AS prod
                        WHERE prod.ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                            AND prod.GroupLevel=5
                        FOR XML PATH('productLevel_previously_level_5'),ROOT('products'),TYPE  
                    )*/
                FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl3
                WHERE lvl3.GroupLevel=3 
                AND lvl3.ParentGroupID=lvl2.GroupID
                FOR XML PATH('productGroup3'),TYPE, ELEMENTS
            )    
        FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl2
        WHERE lvl2.GroupLevel=2 
        AND lvl2.ParentGroupID=lvl1.GroupID
        order by lvl2.GroupName
        FOR XML PATH('productGroup2'),TYPE, ELEMENTS 
    )      
FROM #tmpFullResult AS lvl1
WHERE lvl1.ParentGroupID IS NULL
order by GroupNumber
FOR XML PATH('productGroup1'),ROOT('root')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! The problem with your solution for 3+ level is that all products (level 3+) are repeated in each Product Group (If I have 3 Product Groups second level but only one Product Group has Products in level 3+ I can see this products in all Product Groups that is wrong.) – Anton Tredder 6 hours ago

Comment: Hi @Alex, I am very sorry but the code is still not really working as I needed. Your code suggestion is great but it only works until level 4 (level 4 goes to level 3) but I need to work with n levels (i.e. level n+1 should go to level n). I try to explain once again... If I have products on several levels: level 1 products level 2 products level 3 products ... level n products.... I updated my question.

Comment: @Anton Tredder, first of all my code works for levels higher than 4. Have you tried? Secondly it is not nice to try to sneak in major changes to your question, now that you have an answer to your original question (  "... how to create a dynamical XML file with max 3 levels, where all items on levels after the third one are merged to(included into) the 3rd level.") Instead of asking me to write the whole project for you, you can try doing it yourself. All this is on top of you replying to my original (and accepted) answer a week later, saying that it does not meet your NEW requirements.

Comment: @Anton Tredder, I also have to point out that I have spent a lot of time trying to help you but expecting me to write a finished product for you is too much.